# Special Character in Include Query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Please help me with below query. When using special characters in include query it's throwing error.

`{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"wildcard": {"core_skills.keyword": "*c(pro*"}}]}}, "size": 0, "aggs": {"group_by_core_skills": {"terms": {"field": "core_skills.keyword", "include": ".*c(pro.*", "size": 2000}}}}`

Above query is throwing error-

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[1:183] [terms] failed to parse field [include]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "[1:183] [terms] failed to parse field [include]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "expected ')' at position 9"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try edit like this:

```
"include": ".*c\\(pro.*",
```